# How to handle inconsistency in email standard for emails with attachments?

Tags: email, curl

**Comparison between normal email and email with attachments**

Normally I send the following request to the email server: `UID FETCH 10518 BODY`, where 10518 is the UID of the email. This gives me information about the body structure of the message. In this case I get the following response:

```
* 1765 FETCH (UID 10518 BODY ((("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7BIT" 18 1)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7BIT" 215 5) "ALTERNATIVE")("IMAGE" "PNG" NIL "<STUFF_I_HAVE_REMOVED_BECAUSE_IT_MAY_BE_IMPORTANT@yahoo.com>" NIL "BASE64" 241928) "MIXED"))
```

I interpret this as the message has two "bodies." One plain text and the other HTML. Both are encoded in 7Bit. Additionally, the email has one .png image attachment encoded in base64.

Next, I would typically call `UID FETCH 10518 BODY[2]` to retrieve the HTML part of the email, but does does not work when the email contains attachments. Instead the command returns the attachment. Moreover, `UID FETCH 10518 BODY[1]`, which should only return the plain text portion, returns the following:

Returned header:

```
* 1765 FETCH (UID 10518 BODY[1] {528}
------=_Part_9965789_408526439.1704691920004
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello how are you?
------=_Part_9965789_408526439.1704691920004
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><head></head><body><div class="yahoo-style-wrap" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;"><div dir="ltr" data-setdir="false">Hello how are you?</div></div></body></html>
------=_Part_9965789_408526439.1704691920004--
)
A007 OK Success
```

Returned body

```
* 1765 FETCH (UID 10518 BODY[1] {528}
```

No, the body and header are not switched.

**Question**

This is fundamentally different from every other email.
Some issues:

- How do I know `------=_Part_9965789_408526439.1704691920004` is the deliminator I must use? From experience, this string is different per email. It also does not necessary follow what happens to be returned in the body. (Does not always follow `* 1765 FETCH (UID 10518 BODY[1] {528}` in this case).
- Is this consistent and standard behavior? Do I just have to account for the fact that all emails with attachments will beheave this way and all emails without attachments will not? As much as I hope not the email standard has very much failed to impress me thus far.

**For the sake of providing a minimum example:**

Command to get body structure:

```
curl -u email:password --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX" --ssl-reqd --request "UID FETCH 10518 BODY"
```

Change 10518 with the UID of a email in your inbox that contains attachments.
Command to get email body:

```
curl -u email:password --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX" --ssl-reqd --request "UID FETCH 10518 BODY[i]"
```

Where i is the index of the body part starting at 1.

Note: my program is written in cpp, but these curl commands in the terminal return precisely the same content.